# How is metadata represented in sentiment analysis?

Tags: natural-language, transformers, sentiment-analysis

There are papers on semantic analysis using metadata such as "Sentiment Classification on Steam Reviews" (https://cs229.stanford.edu/proj2017/final-reports/5244171.pdf) and "Detecting the Correlation between Sentiment and User-level as
well as Text-Level Meta-data from Benchmark Corpora" (https://shubhanshu.com/assets/papers/metadata-sentiment.pdf), but I don't seem to understand how metadata is concatenated onto the data.

For example, "Sentiment Classification on Steam Reviews" includes metadata such as "people found helpful", "people found funny", "hours played" in their dataset. So, do they just concatenate the metadata at the end (i.e., `This game was funny 10 15 16.5`) or do they put it in human readable language (i.e., `This game was funny; Found helpful: 10; Found funny: 15; Hours played: 16.5`)?

If both are viable, what are the advantages and disadvantages of either one?

Comment: Let's not mix up class projects with peer-reviewed papers. Still, they don't do either thing you describe. Both of your links use passage features and metadata features as inputs to a standard statistical classifier—like logistic regression or multinomial naive Bayes. There's no need to convert the metadata into text.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy Sorry! You're right about the mistake about the project with the Steam reviews. My problem then is that I want to use metadata with a Transformer-like model i.e. taking an input sequence and outputting an output sequence. Do you have any resources or information about this situation?